# How to generate mouse event programmatically?

Tags: events, emacs, mouse

There are two very useful functions in SLIME: `slime-copy-or-inspect-presentation-at-mouse` and `slime-presentation-menu`. But they must be called with an event argument. In order to generate an even I'd need to do a lot of logistics (calculating the region occupied by a printed representation of the object the "mouse" is currently pointing at, lines and columns - something I don't really want to do because, certainly there's something in Emacs that calculates all that stuff already.

So, is there an easy way to generate "fake" mouse event? Because using mouse for only two things in an editor that otherwise doesn't require mouse feels... well, not very smart. :)

**EDIT**

Here's what I've tried:

```
(define-key lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-x ?")
  #'(lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (message "called")
      (slime-copy-or-inspect-presentation-at-mouse
       `(mouse-2 ;; button
     (,(selected-window) ;; window
      ,(point) ;; position
      (0 . 0) ;; window-relative pixel
      0 ;; timestamp
      nil ;; object
      ,(point) ;; text position 
      (,(current-column) . ;; column
       ,(line-number-at-pos (point))) ;; line
      nil ;; image
      (0 . 0) ;; object-relative pixel
      (1 . 1))))))
(define-key lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-x SPC")
  #'(lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (message "called")
      (slime-presentation-menu
       `(mouse-3 ;; button
     (,(selected-window) ;; window
      ,(point) ;; position
      (0 . 0) ;; window-relative pixel
      0 ;; timestamp
      nil ;; object
      ,(point) ;; text position 
      (,(current-column) . ;; column
       ,(line-number-at-pos (point))) ;; line
      nil ;; image
      (0 . 0) ;; object-relative pixel
      (1 . 1))))))
```

And this actually can get me to the point where it displays menu, but when `slime-presentation-menu` calls any of the functions bound to menu items they somehow see that they weren't called with a "real" mouse event, throw and exit. :(

**EDIT2**

I actually think this is because of the `x-popup-menu`, which dispatches different events when you select a menu item with mouse or with keyboard... arrrrrgh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands that expect to be bound to a mouse click take an event parameter.  This is a list full of stuff like the button clicked, the position, the window, etc.  See [21.7.4 Click Events in the Elisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Click-Events.html).

Here's a simple example to fake a scroll wheel event:

```lisp
(mwheel-scroll `(mouse-5 ;; button
                 (,(selected-window) ;; window
                  ,(point) ;; position
                  (0 . 0) ;; window-relative pixel
                  0 ;; timestamp
                  nil ;; object
                  ,(point) ;; text position 
                  (,(current-column) . ;; column
                   ,(line-number-at-pos (point))) ;; line
                  nil ;; image
                  (0 . 0) ;; object-relative pixel
                  (1 . 1)))) ;; object size
```

Here's an example of a real event:

```lisp
'(mouse-4
  (#<window 374 on *scratch*>
   120
   (6 . 10)
   1301935153
   nil
   120
   (0 . 0)
   nil
   (6 . 10)
   (7 . 15)))
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with slime, but glancing at the source, it looks like the functions you mention call slime-presentation-around-click, which in turn calls slime-presentation-around-point.  It seems like it translates a click to a point, so you should be able to write similar functions that use slime-presentation-around-point directly.  I'm looking at slime-20100722 from Ubuntu.

Comment: `posn-at-point` does mostly that, I think. I wonder if it's only available in recent emacs?

Answer (score 1):

`posn-at-point` does almost the right thing. Here's a way to compare its output to a real mouse event:

```
(defun my/test-posn (e)
  (interactive "e")
  (message "%S\n%S" e `(down-mouse-3 ,(posn-at-point))))

(global-set-key [down-mouse-3] #'my/test-posn)
```

Output:

```
(down-mouse-3 (#<window 73 on blah> 3152 (0 . 594) 145393072 nil 3152 (0 . 33) nil (1 . 4) (8 . 18)))
(down-mouse-3 (#<window 73 on blah> 3152 (0 . 594) 0         nil 3152 (0 . 33) nil (0 . 0) (8 . 18)))
```